# How to draw gradient or stylish line canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, paint

**This is my activity where i am using to draw the dotted line . but i want to draw gradient or some style in line ..**

**DragObserverLayout.java**

```
//class for draw line from one place to another
public class DragObserverLayout extends RelativeLayout {

  float startX, startY, stopX, stopY;
  private Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
  private List<Rect> lines = new ArrayList<Rect>();
  public List<Path> linePath = new ArrayList<Path>();

    //class for dragging
public DragObserverLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    //setting color stroke and effect
    mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    mPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.BUTT);
    mPaint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] {5,5}, 0));
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10.0f);

}

//for canvas
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    final int count = lines.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final Rect r = lines.get(i);

        canvas.drawLine(r.left, r.top, r.right, r.bottom, mPaint);

    }

}
```

Comment: Please write proper line and tell me where i have to use ??

Comment: what proper line? what do you mean?

Comment: i dont know how to use setShader so can you show some example

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: i tried bitmap , also tried shader but nothing is happening so i am here in StackOverflow

Comment: so show what you  tried with shader then

Comment: paint.setShader(new LinearGradient(100,200,230,310, 0x00ffff00,0x44ffff00, TileMode.CLAMP));  i user this but nothing happen

Comment: just getting difference in color nothing more than this

Comment: you wanted to draw a gradient,  right? so LinearGradiebt is what you want,  isn't it?

Comment: actually i am making object matching game ,, and i used line from one object to another ,,, but line is looking very simple .. so i want to make this line stylish .. just like arrow type or some gradient .. but  unable to do .. so tell me the perfect way

Comment: if you want to draw a line in some gradient colors and not in solid color use setShader and LinearGradient

Comment: i found the way thank you for your help , i tried just like this ..     mPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10.0f);
        RadialGradient gradient = new RadialGradient(100, 100, 100, 0xFF000066,
                0xFFFFFFFF, android.graphics.Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
        mPaint.setShader(gradient);